# Не сохраняются данные в Heroku

Tags: python, flask, heroku

Я создал сайт на Python, Flask, и после того этого я его решил загрузить на сервер Heroku, и проблема в том что у меня все сохраняется в .db, если я добавляю какие-то записи они у меня сохраняются и все нормально и они отображаются на сайте. Но после того как сервер heroku уходит в спящий режим, он все стирает что я написал при включенном сайте, и если я зайду снова на сайт там ничего не будет. Как сделать так чтобы он сохранял данные на вечно?

Comment: Хоть кто-нибудь читает документацию? На Heroku файловая система временная.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, а можно чтобы он сохранял их на долго

Comment: Нет, нельзя. Используйте [полноценную СУБД](https://www.heroku.com/postgres).